# Extent4.0 report is not generating with the below code

Tags: java, selenium, extentreports

I am new to Java and Selenium programming and have an critical assignment that needs to be completed soon. I am using Page Object Model framework and trying to generate extent reports. Extent4.0 report is not generating with the below code. The code works fine and TestNg reports generates just fine. Please assist.

```
package testcases;    
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentHtmlReporter;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.configuration.Theme;
import base.CommonMethods;
import pages.HomePage;

public class BaseTest extends CommonMethods {
    public ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;
    public ExtentReports extent;
    public ExtentTest logger;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void startReport() {
        htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(
                System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/test-output/Ruchita/STMExtentReport.html");
        extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
        extent.setSystemInfo("OS", "Windows");
        extent.setSystemInfo("Environment", "QA");
        extent.setSystemInfo("User Name", "Ruchita");
        htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("Automation Report");
        // Name of the report
        htmlReporter.config().setReportName("Functional Tests ");
        // Dark Theme
        htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.DARK);
    }
    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup() {
        instatiateBrowser();
    }
    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        extent.flush();
        driver.quit();

    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void validateHomePageTitleTest() {
        // log.info("******************Starting
        // validateHomePageTitleTest****************" );
        HomePage homePage = new HomePage();
        homePage.validateHomePageTitle();
    }
    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void ValidateLogoImageTest() {
        // log.info("******************Starting
        // ValidateLogoImageTest*******************" );
        HomePage homePage = new HomePage();
        homePage.ValidateLogoImage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i know that in some version it been change to this

try to change from line

```
       ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("*YourName*");
```

to

```
      ExtentSparkReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentSparkReporter("*YourName*");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code as below. It should generate the report now. If you still facing the issues , please post in the comments and will help you

```
package testcases;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.Status;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.markuputils.ExtentColor;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.markuputils.MarkupHelper;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentHtmlReporter;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.configuration.Theme;

public class BasePage {
    public ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;
    public ExtentReports extent;
    public ExtentTest logger;

    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void startReport() {
        htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(
                System.getProperty("user.dir") +"/test-output/testReport.html");
        extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
        extent.setSystemInfo("OS", "Windows");
        extent.setSystemInfo("Environment", "QA");
        extent.setSystemInfo("User Name", "Ruchita");
        htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("Automation Report");
        // Name of the report
        htmlReporter.config().setReportName("Functional Tests ");
        // Dark Theme
        htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.DARK);
    }
    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup() {
        //instatiateBrowser();
    }
    @AfterMethod
    public void getResult(ITestResult result) {

        if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
            logger.log(Status.FAIL, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName() + " is Failed", ExtentColor.RED));
            logger.fail(result.getThrowable());
        }
        else if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {
            logger.log(Status.PASS, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName()+" is Passed", ExtentColor.GREEN));
        }
        else {
            logger.log(Status.SKIP, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName()+" is Failed", ExtentColor.ORANGE));
            logger.skip(result.getThrowable());
        }
    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void validateHomePageTitleTest() {
        logger = extent.createTest("Validate Home Page Title", "Validate Home Page");
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
        logger.log(Status.PASS, "sample test for passed");
    }
    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void ValidateLogoImageTest() {
        logger = extent.createTest("Validate Logo Image ", "Validate Logo Image Test");
        Assert.assertTrue(false);
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void TearDown() {
        extent.flush();
    }
}
```

Report Screenshot:
[image]